# A Console.WriteLine("text" + function(parameter)); don't work but this instruction split into two Console.Write work fine

Tags: c#

I started to use C# a few days ago within an algorithm course. 
I have a homework and there is something I need explanation for. 
I need to create a hangman game with three levels, each level has four words to be guessed.

What I want to print on the screen is:

> Level 1 : oooo
>   Level 2 : oooo
>   Level 3 : oooo

The "emtpy circle" will be filled each time a word is found within a level.

To render this, I decided to create a `char[ ]`.

Here is the function I am using:

```
public static char[] DisplayEmptyCircles(List<string> listLevel)
{
    char[] emptyCircle = new char[listLevel.Count];
    for (int counterCircles = 0; counterCircles < listLevel.Count; counterCircles++)
    {
        emptyCircle[counterCircles] = Convert.ToChar(9675);             
    }
    return emptyCircle;
}
```

When I use these two separate instructions everything goes well:

```
Console.Write("Level 1 : ");
Console.Write(DisplayEmptyCircles(firstLevel));
```

But I first used this one and got a `System.Char[ ]` printed instead of the empty circles :

```
Console.WriteLine("Level 1 : " + DisplayEmptyCircles(firstLevel));
```

Can someone tell me why?

I am sorry I know the question was asked already but I know barely nothing about C#. It's just to start learning and understanding.

Comment: If you call it separately, then one of [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.7.2) is used which does extra work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Your `DisplayEmptyCircles` returns an array of `char`, so it cannot be concatenated to a string. You can either make your function return a string or convert its result to string when you call `Console.Write`.

If you just want to create a string containing N circles, then it can be achieved in a simpler way:

```
public static string DisplayEmptyCircles(int count)
{
    return new string((char)9675, count);
}

Console.WriteLine("Level 1 : " + DisplayEmptyCircles(firstLevel.Count));
```

Some more changes in the code:

- It doesn't use `char[]` and utilizes [`String(char c, int count)` constuctor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_)
- `DisplayEmptyCircles` doesn't actually need information about levels, it only needs the count
- You don't need to use `Convert.ToChar`, because it just does some additional checks, which are redundant when you have a constant value

Answer (score 3):

The `Console.WriteLine` converts your **char array** to a **string**. But it can't convert the combination of **string + char array**. So you have to convert the **char array** to a **string**. You can do it in your static function or on the fly.

*In your static function:*

```
public static string DisplayEmptyCircles(List<string> listLevel)
{
    char[] emptyCircle = new char[listLevel.Count];
    for (int counterCircles = 0; counterCircles < listLevel.Count; counterCircles++)
    {
        emptyCircle[counterCircles] = Convert.ToChar(9675);             
    }
    return new string(emptyCircle);
}
```

*On the fly:*

```
Console.WriteLine("Level 1 : " + new string(DisplayEmptyCircles(firstLevel)));
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to convert the char[] in the static function, you should use the approach from **Yeldar Kurmangaliyev**!

Answer (score 2):

This is because `Console.Write()` will use `char[]` as input and in `Console.WriteLine(...)` you will end up with converting `char[]` to string with `.ToString()` method. Use `new string( DisplayEmptyCircles(firstLevel))`

```
Console.WriteLine("Level 1 : " + new string(DisplayEmptyCircles(firstLevel)));
```